# Any way to convert IPv4 packet to IPv6?

Tags: c#

I am using `PcanDotNet`  DLLs and i wonder if there is any way to convert Ipv4 packet to Ipv6 
I don't think this DLLs support this so i need to do it on my own with this DLLs help but my question is if is possible to convert.

Comment: please check this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8edb8091-bc53-48ea-91a0-3ceb395f80c6/how-to-convert-ipv6-address-shortenedalternative-formats-to-preferred-ipv6-address?forum=csharpgeneral, hope it will help you

Comment: After try this solution IP Address 192.168.0.1 become 192.168.000.001

Comment: this will convert the ip to its default format, below is the solution for your case hopefully

Comment: I found this site: http://www.nish.com/2009/11/convert-ipv4-into-ipv6/ ipv4 192.168.25.234 become into C0A8:19EA but the whole address should be fe80:0:0:0:0:0:C0A8:19EA in case i want to use this, how i know what to add to my address ? (beofore C0A8:19EA in this example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.maptoipv6.aspx)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: With this method 192.168.0.1 converted into ::ffff:192.168.0.1, but the correct address should be fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:1, why this different ?

Comment: can you give in the code that you tried?

Comment: This is the online convertor: http://ipv6.ztsoftware.net/ipv4-to-ipv6/, what i have try is the method you mention

Comment: I guess both are same representation .. I tried converting both the results to IPV4 with .MapToIPv4() and both of them gave "192.168.0.1".

Answer (score 0):

suppose the IPV4="192.168.0.1"

here what you can do

```
var ip = "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:192.168.0.1";
System.Net.IPAddress address = null;
System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out address);
```

now if you check the address.AddressFamily  => InterNetworkV6

hope that this will help you

regards